# General Solution of x' = Ax found by Eigenvalue method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that
$$ A = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 2 \\
    2 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then $e^{At} = I \cos(2t)+ \frac{A}{2} \sin(2t)$.
How is this fact applied to a **general solution of $x' = Ax$** using the Eigenvalue method?

Comment: To do this you need [Caley-hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#Matrix_functions) in the link to wikipedia they do same for the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$ and get $e^{At} = I \cos(t)+ A \sin(t)$ and here at [math.stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=cayley+hamilton+exponential) you can find more proofs, also notice that $(xe^{-at})'=x'e^{-at}-xae^{-at}=e^{-at}(x'-ax)$ and the same happens with matrices, hope it helps

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> How is this fact applied to a **general solution of $x' = Ax$** using the Eigenvalue method?

The general solution to your problem $x'(t) = Ax(t) + b$ in terms of the matrix exponential of $A$ is 
$$x(t) = x^* + e^{At}(x(0) - x^*) $$
where $x(0) = x(t=0)$ and $x^* = -A^{-1}b = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&2\\ 2&0\end{array}\right)=U^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&2i\\ -2i&0\end{array}\right)U
$$
where
$$
U=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&i\\ 1&0\end{array}\right)
$$
and hence
$$
x(t)=e^{tA}=U^{-1}\exp\bigg(t\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&2i\\ -2i&0\end{array}\right)\bigg)U=
U^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos(2t)&i\sin (2t)\\ -i\sin(2t)&\cos(2t)\end{array}\right)U=
\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos(2t)&\sin (2t)\\ \sin(2t)&\cos(2t)\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: Excuse me, I've been informed the question was wrong...A should be [0 2][-2 0] and not [0 2][2 0]; is the correct answer in fact what you were assuming?